# Ionic 4 - Property 'dataDirectory' does not exist on type 'File' error build android

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

Has anyone seen this error `Property 'dataDirectory' does not exist on type 'File'`?

I imported that way in the file `app.module.ts`: `import { File } from '@ionic-native/File/ngx'`

And, in the component, I'm calling the File plugin just like that:

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  let path = this.file.dataDirectory
  this.file.checkDir(path, MEDIA_FOLDER_NAME).then(() => {
    this.loadFiles()
  }, err => {
    this.file.createDir(path, MEDIA_FOLDER_NAME, false)
  })
})
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Thank you! :)

```
Ionic v4.7.1
@ionic-native/file v5.27.0
cordova-plugin-file v6.0.2
```

Comment: In the import path 'f' should be small, import { File } from `'@ionic-native/file/ngx'` for the right path. And please do install it to a device or emulator and then check, might not get the directory on ionic-serve

Comment: @NavKumarV I change that, and the erros continues just in release build. In a emulator, run's fine!

Comment: I have one doubt, have you imported `import { File } from '@ionic-native/File/ngx'` even in the component where u are using it?. `if No`, then u will have to import it in the component. **OR** `If yes` then please check the below explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back to version 5.0.0 and solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with the same versions that you had specified in a new project, where `this.file.dataDirectory` is present and working fine even in release build. Then I think the issue might be that there is another reference of `File` in your project which might be causing this issue.

I can refer you 2 suggestions:

1. Find the other definition of `File` and rename it. **OR**
2. Try changing as below code

```
import { File as Native_File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';

constructor(private file: Native_File){}
```